# Substitute different values for the same line and stay together after the SUBSTITUTE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

COLUMN A

```
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
```

COLUMN B

```
wilson/@@@@/
jonas/@@@@/
```

COLUMN C

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({
SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,"/@@@@/",A1);
SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,"/@@@@/",A2);
SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,"/@@@@/",A3);
SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,"/@@@@/",A4);
SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,"/@@@@/",A5)
}),"Where Col1 <>''")),"/teste/clean/save/")
```

RESULT COLUMN C

```
wilson/2020/
jonas/2020/
wilson/2021/
jonas/2021/
wilson/2022/
jonas/2022/
wilson/2023/
jonas/2023/
wilson/2024/
jonas/2024/
```

EXPECTED RESULT COLUMN C

```
wilson/2020/
wilson/2021/
wilson/2022/
wilson/2023/
wilson/2024/
jonas/2020/
jonas/2021/
jonas/2022/
jonas/2023/
jonas/2024/
```

**NOTE: I cannot use `Order by Col1` in the `QUERY` because the values will not be sorted alphabetically, they need to be together after the `SUBSTITUTE`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B2, "@@@@", TRANSPOSE(A1:A5))))
```

[image]